# Remix Solidity Parsererror expected Identifier but got 'string literal" string public

Tags: solidity

Any help much appreciated!

getting error on "string public "Test Token";" line

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }

contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public "Test Token";
    string public "TEST";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public 100000000;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing variables names for "Test Token" and "TEST" strings.

This will work.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { 

    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; 

}

contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token 
    string public name = "Test Token"; 
    string public name2 =  "TEST"; 
    uint8 public decimals = 18; // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it uint256 public 100000000;
}
```

Next time please try to format your code snippet when asking question. It is easier to read. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!  I will try to format code snippet next time!

Answer (score 1):

No variable names are declared as of your code. That's only is the problem, solidity need some variable name to store a string or whatever it is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }

contract TokenERC20 {
   // Public variables of the token
   string public testToken = "Test Token";
   string public test = "TEST";
   uint8 public decimals = 18;
   // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
uint256 public bigNumber = 100000000;
```